# For some reason my unslider doesn't scale with the screen.. fiddle included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am using unslider to make a slide show that is 100% wide for a site. It works perfect on load but for some reason when I resize the screen the slides stay the same size they were on load. Here is the mark up http://jsfiddle.net/MLh9k/ I used

```
width:100%;
```

on the slides but that didn't work. Honestly I am new to slide shows but am great with html and css and a tiny bit of javascript implementation. If there is any other simpler way to create a slide show that is 100% wide, each slide can have buttons and text as well as a centered responsive background image please include some fiddles. I appreciate all of your help.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding an option from the slider called `fluid: true`. It will look something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.banner').unslider({
        fluid: true
    });
});
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/MLh9k/1/

Comment: i know it is a nood question but.. how do i add those other options, when i put speed: 500,  for example it broke the code.. any ideas?

Comment: You have to separate the options by a comma, so fluid: true, speed: 500

Comment: Yup! That's typically how a jQuery plugin works, so once you get used to one, you're familiar with the layout of all of them.

Comment: one last question... when I use an image instead of a color the image doesn't streach along the size of the browser like it does on their site. is there  a way i can make it fit most of the image inside the specified height and width?

Comment: If you just set the width of the image to 100%, it will scale it's height and width to the size of its parent.

Comment: can you include a fiddle please? It still doesn't work for me

Comment: adding min-height to your code did the trick. Thanks alot pal!

Comment: do you know how i can add touch?

Comment: Um, don't know if that slider has that option